# How to differentiate 2 classes: digits and "other letters and noise" on an image?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, haar-classifier, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I develop an image recognition algorithm that helps to find characters on dirty pannels from the real world. Actually the image is a car registering plate containing letters, digits and a mud.

The algorithm must classify characters into two classes: alphabet characters and digits. Is it possible to train LBP or Haar cascade to discriminate between the two classes, will be training result stable due to digits shape variety?

Could you explain briefly or recommend better method, please?

Answer (score 0):

"The algorithm must classify characters into two classes: alphabet characters and digits.” - you forgot mud and background though technically you can add them to a broad category “other”. Haars cascades are used for something like face detection since they typically approximate wavelets on the middle spatial scale where faces have characteristic features. Your problem is different.You need to first understand your problem structure, read the literature and only then try to use a sheer force of learning algorithms. This [book](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/s.prince/book/book.pdf) actually talks a bit about people starting to think about method first instead of analyzing the problem which is not always a good idea.

Technically you first need to find the text in the image which can be more challenging than recognizing it given the current state of art OCR that is typically used as a library rather than created from scratch. To find text in the image I suggest first do adaptive thresholding to create a binary map (1-foreground that is letters and numbers and 0 is background), then perform connected components on the foreground coupled with SWT (stroke width transform) http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/149305/1509.pdf